# Considering authentication when using Ajax with Spring MVC

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, spring, authentication, spring-security

I am trying to use ajax in my spring mvc application. When I try a url (post/get) which is secured and needs authentication, the response is the html of login page as it is redirected behind the scenes.
What is the best approach to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1):

First, I would avoid displaying Ajax links to URLs needing authentication if the user is not authenticated, if possible.

If not always possible, your login page could be returned with a specific HTTP response code, (or any other way to distinguish it from a normal response) and your JavaScript callback could replace the entire body of the current page with the HTML received if this response code is received. Most AJAX libraries come with a way to define a handler to all the AJAX requests. Such a global handler could be used here.

The login page could also be adapted to only return a status code in case of an AJAX request, and the JavaScript code would then redirect to the login page (without using AJAX) if this status code is received.

Answer (score 1):

I may not have explained the issue well. So I did not get the right response. However the response from JB Nizet contained some other points. So thank you.

I could solve the issue after coming back to this issue after some time, so
[I posted about this on my blog](https://blog.rezajp.info/posts/returning-401-or-403-for-ajax-requests-w/).

I hope it is useful.